# How to set up a minimal TLS: Configure client and server, or implement my own?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, https

I am looking for advice on how to best implement an M2M TLS-connection. different from "normal" web traffic, we control both client and server, and thus can nail down the cipher string to exactly one option. How do I go about setting up the client and server?
A) If there are no cipher string options, I can greatly simplify the code and remove all branches - which helps to avoid bugs and security flaws. On the other hand, we have to mess with the code.
B) Use standard client libraries and server software, and minimize the configuration to the one exact cipher we use.

I have never implemented TLS myself, and I have not yet attempted a minimal TLS configuration, either. Which one you think is easier to get right?

Thanks very much for your opinions!
Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have never implemented TLS myself, and I have not yet attempted a minimal TLS configuration, either. Which one you think is easier to get right?

If you look at the problems with the different TLS stacks last year (all major stacks had serious bugs) you can either assume that the developers of these stacks are all stupid or that writing a secure stack is hard. I think it is the last option and since you have no experience with TLS yet I predict that any stack you write will be even more buggy than the existing ones. So you better use an existing stack.

Comment: A lot of the recent problems with TLS wouldn't affect a minimal implementation that only supports TLS 1.2 and only one AEAD suite. Several were CBC related, some related to client certificates or version negotiation.

Comment: All what I tried to say is that implementing TLS correctly is hard. Most of the problems last year where implementation errors (Heartbleet, goto fail, WinShock...) and not design errors. And then there are timing attacks which open side channels ... . The chance is low that somebody without current knowledge of TLS will successfully take care of all these problems.

Comment: Thanks very much for your opinions. I think many of the TLS bugs   resulted from the complexity of the TLS specification. It is fiendishly difficult to get all the possible combinations of ciphers, authentication, key exchange, etc. right. But if I rely on, say, Bouncy Castle for the  cryptography, and only use those classes and methods I need, the branch complexity will be reduced. Is it simpler to proceed this way than to properly  configure the minimum TLS I am looking for AND have the regular TLS implementation be less buggy in this configuration than my proposed own implementation?

Comment: From my experience it is much safer to rely on established common knowledge and use a TLS stack with known but acceptable problems than to create something new, even if from existing parts. If you had the deep knowledge necessary to combine existing cryptographic parts in a secure way then you would probably not need to ask for suggestions here. Again, the programmers of the existing stacks are not stupid and mostly know what they do and they still introduce bugs.